# Postgres: join queries with different number of columns into a single result set?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.4. I have a table like this:

```
 org_id            | character varying(3)    | not null
 drug_code         | character varying(15)   | not null
 actual_cost       | double precision        | not null
 processing_date   | date                    | not null
```

And I want to run a query like this:

```
 SELECT org_id, SUM(actual_cost) AS cost_123 FROM mytable
 WHERE drug_code='123'
 AND processing_date < '2014-03-01' 
 AND processing_date > '2014-01-10'
 GROUP BY org_id
```

which produces:

```
   org_id    cost_123   
   1         200.12    
   2         400.15
```

And another query like this:

```
 SELECT org_id, SUM(actual_cost) AS cost_234 FROM mytable
 WHERE drug_code='234'
 AND processing_date < '2014-03-01' 
 AND processing_date > '2014-01-10'
 GROUP BY org_id
```

which produces:

```
   org_id    cost_123   
   2         68.98    
   3         66.54
```

And get a single set of results like this:

```
org_id    cost_123   cost_234
1         200.12     NULL 
2         400.15     68.98
3         NULL       66.54
```

Is this possible with Postgres?

I've been looking at `[UNION][1]` but it seems to imply that the results have to be in the same order, which I can't guarantee. I can't even guarantee that there will be the same number of columns, because not all organisations will have spent on all drugs in every month.

Do I need to make a new table, and run queries on that? Or join my data offline?

Answer (score 2):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT org_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN drug_code = '123' THEN actual_cost ELSE 0 END) AS cost_123,
        SUM(CASE WHEN drug_code = '234' THEN actual_cost ELSE 0 END) AS cost_234 FROM mytable
 WHERE drug_code in ('123', '234') AND
       processing_date < '2014-03-01' AND
       processing_date > '2014-01-10'
 GROUP BY org_id;
```